# How to format an underline for a navigation bar using CSS

Tags: html, css, format, underline

I figured out how to make an underline under a part of my navigation bar when I am hovering over the word. I am trying to make it in the same format for when I am on that page so that the underline stays there. I can't figure this out. Would love some help.
Thanks :)

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}


.topnav {
    background-color: purple;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .topnav a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }

 .topnav a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>
    Change
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">DontUse</a>
    <a href="#contact">DontUse</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    This is the home page
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, using jquery. 
Also  made a new active-menu class `.topnav a.active-menu:before`

```js
$("a").click(function(){
   $("a.active-menu").removeClass("active-menu");
   $(this).addClass("active-menu");
});
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}


.topnav {
    background-color: purple;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .topnav a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }

 .topnav a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
.topnav a.active-menu:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>
    Change
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="active-menu" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#news">DontUse</a>
    <a class="link" href="#contact">DontUse</a>
    <a class="link" href="about.html">About</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    This is the home page
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you check why this isn't working. I updated it here: https://jsfiddle.net/rfradkin/h4wpguc9/2/

Comment: @rf19 because you haven't selected in Frameworks & Extensions jQuery library witch my solution uses. Click on JavaScript + No-Library (pure JS), and select  in Frameworks & Extensions latest  jQuery. If you have local or hosted files you need to add jQuery there also in order for this to work. You can google how to do that.

Comment: @rf19 this can be writen in pure JS code too of you dont want to use librerys, but is lot more code, and I dont have time now for that. If you need it leave me a msg ill find some tomorow.