# How to underline a navigation bar using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

@ikiK I've tried to implement your solution, but it has not worked. All my files are in the same folder and the html file is called index.html, the css file is called style.css and the jquery file is called script.js    I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, so if you could walk me through how to fix it, that would be much appreciated.

```js
$("a").click(function(){
    $("a.active-menu").removeClass("active-menu");
    $(this).addClass("active-menu");
 });
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}


.topnav {
    background-color: purple;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .topnav a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }

 .topnav a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
.topnav a.active-menu:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; 
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>
    Change
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="active-menu" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#news">DontUse</a>
    <a class="link" href="#contact">DontUse</a>
    <a class="link" href="about.html">About</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    This is the home page
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are clearly referring to some previous conversation. If this is a follow up question, please reference the original one. Also please be clear in what is your goal. What do you want to achieve with your code and what are the issues your are facing?

Comment: Here is the original problem and conversation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61786026/how-to-format-an-underline-for-a-navigation-bar-using-css

Comment: I'm trying to have an underline hold in the navigation bar in the same style as when you hover when you are on that web page

Comment: Please edit your question to include the link and the problem statement.

Comment: When I run the snippet here at SO, the menu items show an animated underline on hover. Also the underline stays on the selected menu item. Is that what you want to achieve, or is it something else?

Comment: That's it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## explanation

You can't (or shouldn't) change it on hover using jquery. instead, when navigating to a different page, manually take the active-menu class off of one link, and then to another. example:

## example

### index.html

```
<body>
  <div class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="active-menu" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">DontUse</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">DontUse</a>
    <a class="link" href="about/index.html">About</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    This is the home page
  </p>
</body>
```

## about/index.html

```
<body>
  <div class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#news">DontUse</a>
    <a class="link" href="#contact">DontUse</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="about.html">About</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    This is the about page
  </p>
</body>
```

## note

if you want the active links to not work, then replace the name (e.g. `index.html` with `#`.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see is `}` too much in the first snippet. It closes the function too early. It should be:

```js
$("a").click(function(){
    $("a.active-menu").removeClass("active-menu");
    $(this).addClass("active-menu");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just updated this but it still isn't working

Comment: You have to be more specific about what doesn't work and what you are trying to achieve. Btw I don't see the update yet.